# Is there a relationship between a data source (JSON) and the Model that consumes it?

Tags: javascript, architecture

I have put together a large quiz data structure. It is in JSON format but I guess it could be XML etc.  It may look something like this simplified:

```
{
   "quiz":{

       "title": "Welcome to Quiz"
       "entries": [

            {

                "question": "programmers.so is awesome?"
                "answers": [
                     {
                         "answer": "Yes"   
                     },
                     {
                         "answer": "Yes!"   
                     }
                ]
            }
       ]
    }
}
```

I now need to make an application which can consume this data. I am going to start by getting it loaded and putting it into Models.

But... The data here does not represent all the data I need. Say for example that when you select an answer, I am going to want to keep track of what answer was selected.

That information does not belong in the data.

Do I want to base my model structure on the JSON structure or do I keep it separate?

`Has` the data

```
class Model {

    protected data: IQuizJSON;

    constructor(data: IQuizJSON){

          this.data = data;

          //use the data to construct unpolluted models 

    }

}
```

`Is` the data

```
class Model {

    title: string;
    entries: Entry[];

    constructor(data: IQuizJSON){

          this.title = data.title;
          this.entries = [];
          for (var i: number = 0; i < data.entries.length; i++){
               this.entries.push(new Entry(data.entries[i]));
          }

    }

}
class Entry implements IQuizEntry {

     question: string;

     constructor(data: IQuizEntryJSON){

          this.question = new Question(data.question); //etc

     }

}
```

Until now I have read about how Models and Views interact, but here the data and model seem to merge and I am not sure of the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many models as you need to meet the many goals that a successful application has to address.

One concept that might help here is the Single Responsibility Principle. Basically, you ask the question, "what would cause this data structure to change?" In your case, changing the details of the quiz structure would be a prime source for change. Hence, your base data model reflects all and only the external representation.

A second part of your business object, though, is the ability to track what answer was selected, for instance. In general you would want a second data structure to retain the information about selections. Certainly, you would want to store those statistics separately from the sources for your quiz. Among other things, you might want to store correlations of answer selection with other answers selected, or which people selected which answer.

So the answer is that you need to create an aggregate data structure which contains a data structure that matches the quiz representation, as well as a data structure that stores statistics of interest.

Additionally, you really don't want to have the argument to the constructor be the JSON data. It is much better to have a factory, along with a builder. This would allow you to switch to XML, say, as your external representation, and that should not require changing your base model.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. You brought up a lot of new avenues of thought so I will explore tonight with a beer! Cheers.